# Non-abelian, simple subgroups of $S_n$

Tags: group-theory, sylow-theory

I am trying to prove, as part of a larger theorem, that if $G$ is a non-abelian finite, simple group of order $>2$ and $G$ is a subgroup of $S_n$, then $G$ must be a subgroup of $A_n$.

Any ideas where along which lines I should be thinking? I am allowed to assume basic group theory and Sylow's theorem.

Comment: You don't need Sylow's theorem. All you need is that any subgroup of index $2$ in any group is a normal subgroup.

Answer (score 3):

Hint : consider the restriction of the signature to $G$, as a morphism $G\to \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$. Can it be injective ?

Comment: by signature do you mean the parity homomorphism?

Comment: it's usually called the signature, but yes.

Comment: You probably meant to ask "Can it be surjective?". It can't be injective for reasons of cardinality alone.

Comment: @DanielFischer That's the point. Then you can look at the kernel.

Comment: Ah, yes. You looked at it from the other side.

Comment: Am I right to say that you can always find a non-trivial even permutation in G and thus the kernel of this homomorphism is non-trivial, hence we get a normal subgroup of G which contradicts simplicity? Also, is the non-abelian property redundant in this question?

Comment: Yes, the non-abelian property is redundant. All you need is that $G$ is imple and $|G|>2$.

Comment: The fact that $G$ is included in $A_n$ is equivalent to the fact that the signature $G\to \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ is the trivial morphism. So you have to argue that the kernel must be all of $G$.

Comment: Suppose $G$ is not a subgroup of $A_n$, then $G\cap A_n$ is a non-trivial  proper subgroup of $G$ and the kernel of the signature homomorphism. Thus it is a normal subgroup of $G$, contradicting simplicity of $G$. Hence $G$ must indeed be a subgroup of $A_n$.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach.

Observe that for $\;n=3,4\;$ you can check it directly, as there are no non-abelian simple subgroups of $\;S_n\;$ (the closest thing is a $\;2\,-$ subgroup of order eight in $\;A_4\;$ which of course isn't simple). Suppose thus that $\;n\ge5\;$ :

$$G\rlap{\;\,/}\subset A_n\implies [G:G\cap A_n]=2\implies G\cap A_n\lhd G\implies $$

either $\;G\cap A_n=1\;$ or $\;G\cap A_n=G\;$ as $\;G\;$  is simple. The second relation leads directly to the contradiction $\;G\subset A_n\;$ , whereas the first one leads us either to the fact that we can form the semidirect product $\;A_n\rtimes G\;$ which would have to be equal to $\;S_n\;$ by order considerations and thus $\;G\cong C_2\;$, contradiction, or else, knowing that any subgroup of $\;S_n\;$ is either contained in $\;A_n\;$ or *exactly* half its elements are even permutations, we'd get $\;G\cap A_n=1\implies G=1\;$

Comment: I don't think you should be using the simplicity of $A_n$ for $n \ge 5$. It is unnecessary.

Comment: @DerekHolt Thank you, you're right. That's part of a former argument I changed. Editing now.

Comment: @ChrisChristopherson That's very well known in permutations groups. Let $\;x\in G\;$ be an odd permutation, and define $\;f: G\to G\;$ by $\;f(g):=xg\;$ . Check that this is a bijection from $\;G\;$ onto itself and it maps odd permutations to even ones and viceversa, from which we can pair up odd and even permutations of $\;G\;$. This means $\;G\;$ has the same number of odd permutations as of even ones...

Comment: I would think that assuming $G \cap A_n = 1$ means you're done since this would force $2=|G: G \cap A_n| = \frac{|G|}{|G \cap A_n|} = \frac{|G|}{1}$, i.e. we get $|G|=2$ and so $G$ is abelian, a contradiction to our initial assumption. No need for semidirect product, I would think. Although this is alluded to when $C_2$ is mentioned